# zsh: permission denied: flake8

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip, zsh

I use zsh with oh my zsh, i have installed flake8 using 'pip install flake8' and i changed path to flake8:
`export PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages:$PATH"`

***example of error***

```
❯ python --version
Python 3.10.1
❯ pip --version
pip 21.3.1 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
❯ flake8 --version
zsh: permission denied: flake8
❯ python -m flake8 --version
4.0.1 (flake8-broken-line: 0.4.0, flake8-return: 1.1.3, flake8_isort: 4.1.1, mccabe: 0.6.1,
naming: 0.12.1, pycodestyle: 2.8.0, pyflakes: 2.4.0) CPython 3.10.1 on Darwin
```

`python -m flake8 --version` is works, but `flake8 --version` doesn't work.
How to fix this error?

Comment: Wild guess (I don't know anything about flake): you have a directory or file called `flake8` in your current working dir, and that one is not executable. What happens if you try to run flake8 from a different directory ?

Comment: What happens if you invoke `flake8` by specifying the path explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have done

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages:$PATH"
```

That is only where the python modules reside. I.e. the executable `flake8` does not live in that folder, only a directory with that name containing the pyhton sources exists in that folder. That is where your error is comming from. When you type `flake8` in your `zsh`, the only thing that is found in the PATH is that directory, which cannot be executed.

You need to find out where `pip` has installed the actual executable and (possibly) add that location to path. You can check the location returned by

```
echo `python -m site --user-base`/bin
```

Comment: i have installed python 3.10 using homebrew, this location for python 3.8

Comment: Try with `python` instead of `python3`. Your post suggests that that should point to your python3.10 installation

Comment: just fixed used 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:$PATH" ' but ur answer is useful